# Can we show , without considering the real numbers , that $\mathcal N$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathcal C$?

Tags: analysis, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $\mathcal C :=\{(r_n)\subseteq \mathbb Q : \forall k \in \mathbb Q^+ , \exists N_k \in \mathbb N : |r_n-r_m| < \dfrac1{k} , \forall n,m \ge N_k  \}$ and $\mathcal N:=\{(r_n)\subseteq \mathbb Q : \forall k \in \mathbb Q^+ , \exists N_k \in \mathbb N : |r_n| < \dfrac1{k} , \forall n \ge N_k  \}$ , it is known that $\mathcal C$ forms a commutative ring with unity  under usual point-wise addition and multiplication of seuqneces  ; with the knowledge of real numbers and archimedean property and all that , I can show that $\mathcal N$ is an ideal of $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal C / \mathcal N \cong \mathbb R$ as rings , which shows that $\mathcal N$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathcal C$ . But I want to show , **without considering the real numbers** , that $\mathcal N$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathcal C$ so that I can use the definition $\mathbb R :=\mathcal C / \mathcal N$ , can this be done ?

Comment: Sure, just prove that $C/N$ is a field. Which essentially boils down to proving that sequences which are not in $N$ have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck : Okay , but does that really boils down or so to say is so easy :) ? ( the statements about quitioent ring being field and maximal ideal are euivalent ...)

Comment: Well obviously it's fairly tedious to show that $C/N$ is a field. But once you have proven well-definednes of the field-operations most of the field-axioms follow from those in $\mathbb{Q}$ and essentially what you are left with is the above mentioned multiplicative inverses.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck : So how to show the multiplicative inverse ?? ( I am not bothered about any other field axioms , as I know $\mathcal C / \mathcal N $ is a commutative ring with  unity )

Comment: If you have an element of $s$ of $C$ which is not in $N$ then from some index $n_0$ onwards there won't be any zeros in $s$ any more. Set $s'$ the sequence which is $1$ up to $n_0$ and $s'_n=s_n^{-1}$ for $n>n_0$ (which is possible by the choice of $n_0$). Now prove that this is in fact in $C$ and constitutes an inverse.

Comment: In other words, show any element of $\mathcal{C} - \mathcal{N}$ is a unit, proving the maximality of $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck: This method actually gives much more information. It shows that $\mathcal C$ is a local ring with the unique maximal ideal $\mathcal N.$

Comment: @Krish: No it does not. The sequence which has a $0$ at the first place and $1$ from then onwards is not invertible in $C$ though not an element of $N$ but becomes invertible in $C/N$ since we can ignore finitely many zeros. Hence $C$ is surely not a local ring with maximal ideal $N$.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck: Ah! Sorry. I got confused with "eventually" convergent sequences. Thanks for the clarification.